# Help about : View.setMargins(left , top, right , bottom ) ;

Tags: android, margins

in my application , i use the method setMargins(....) for some views .

in my layout , i fixed the width , heigth and size of my views with 'dp' , not pixels ,

and in my code , when i set Margins , it gives a bad result , but when i change dp with px in my layout , that's work fine .

so my question is : can i set Margins with dp values , ?? 
 example :

```
myView.setMargins(left in dp , top in dp , right in dp , bottom in dp ) ;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can do that easily, just need to define Dimension elements (values strings.xml ) and reference them in your code.

This is line from strings.xml

```
<dimen name="left_border_distance">32dip</dimen>
```

but you do not need to put that directly, rather via IDE.

Then in your code

```
int marginLeft = (int) getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.left_border_distance);
myView.setMargins(marginLeft  , top in dp , right in dp , bottom in dp ) ;
```

Comment: hi , thanks for your quick  answer :p , can you give me an example of that plz , 
Second : is there another way to do this without passing with res/values/strings.xml ??
Thanks Zelimir

Comment: Another approach is described in the answer below. I prefer to put GUI design values to resources, and not to work with hardcoded values in the code. They are easy changeable from one place.

Comment: ur approach is good ,but i'm developping a sdk for ads, so i need to define that in Code , not in strings.xml :)